# How do you style the text inputted to an input text field?

Tags: html, css, input

There are lots of great tutorials on how to apply nice styles to `input type="text"` fields in HTML.

However I'd like to know, how do you style the actual text the user puts into the field? For example, [this input box demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mqrmq/304/) from [DesignWithPc](http://designwithpc.com/post/10562891087/styling-your-input-text-fields-with-css3-gradients).

I've expanded the input box but I want the text typed in to match the size of the box (among other desired styling).

How do I do this?

Comment: There one trick to make text larger that no one knows about. But ok..., I'll tell you. It's `font-size` CSS style.

Comment: I would have felt dumb enough without the theatrics, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `font-size` for that text box.

```
.awesome-text-box{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

This will set the font size of the `.awesome-text-box` textfield to 30px;

Answer (score 0):

You can always achieve this by setting few CSS properties like below

```
.awesome-text-box {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #515151;
}
```

Comment: If Patrick already mentioned it, there's no need to reiterate it.

Comment: Agree but i was forgot to mention few more properties like line heigjt

Comment: @SagarSutar What LittleBobbyTables and MarcelGwerder said are correct, but I really appreciate your effort to help and I see you're new, so +1